Purpose of Secure attribute on cookies on HSTS
I wanted to set the secure attribute to my bearer token cookies, then I remembered that I enforce https on my website. So I didn't think it has any purpose for my use case, but I noticed other sites enforce https only also use the secure attribute for cookies anyway, so what is the use? did I miss something?

It's just another layer of protection that prevents the cookie from accidentally being sent over HTTP. Just because you enforce HTTPS at the server doesn't mean users never try to connect to http://yoursite. A bad guy can potentially wait for such an insecure connection attempt and then pretend to be your site and thereby obtain cookies not marked with the secure attribute.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for the reply, how do I mark your comment as the answer?

It's not an answer, it's just a comment so there is nothing to mark.
